# Preenchimento de barra?

Tags: html, css

Como eu faço para que quando eu abra o site com esse código, ele já "preenche" essa barra e continue preenchida, sem que eu precise ficar com o mouse em cima?

```css
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transform: width 2s; /* Safari */
    transition: width 2s;
 border-radius: 100px;
}

/* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
#div1 {-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;}
#div2 {-webkit-transform-timing-function: ease;}
#div3 {-webkit-transform-timing-function: ease-in;}
#div4 {-webkit-transform-timing-function: ease-out;}
#div5 {-webkit-transform-timing-function: ease-in-out;}

/* Standard syntax */
#div1 {transform-timing-function: linear;}
#div2 {transform-timing-function: ease;}
#div3 {transform-timing-function: ease-in;}
#div4 {transform-timing-function: ease-out;}
#div5 {transform-timing-function: ease-in-out;}

div:hover {
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>

<p><b>Note:</b> This example does not work in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

<div id="div1"></div><br>
<div id="div2"></div><br>
<div id="div3"></div><br>
<div id="div4"></div><br>
<div id="div5"></div><br>

<p>Hover over the div elements above, to see the different speed curves.</p>

</body>
```

Answer (score 6):

É bem simples, a trigger responsável pela animação em seu código é o `hover`, ou seja, só ira executar a animação ao passar o mouse. Para fazer enquanto a página abre, basta criar um keyframe.

Adicionei também durações diferentes para você compreender melhor.

```css
div {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    animation-name: animacao;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

#div1 {
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

#div2 {
  animation-duration: 5s;
}

#div3 {
  animation-duration: 10s;
}

#div4 {
  animation-duration: 15s;
}

#div5 {
  animation-duration: 30s;
}

@keyframes animacao {
    from {width: 50px;}
    to {width: 50%;}
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div><br>
<div id="div2"></div><br>
<div id="div3"></div><br>
<div id="div4"></div><br>
<div id="div5"></div><br>
```

Você pode ler mais sobre animações [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atenção amigo, era bem isso que eu precisava.

Comment: @Fabio legal que consegui te ajudar, só não esqueça de aceitar minha resposta como a melhor resposta :)